# How can I mitigate integer overflow in this code?

Tags: c, integer-overflow, limits

When I input "1073741824", it returns "Segmentation fault".

"1073741824" is 4294967296÷4, which is (INT_MAX+1)÷(sizeof(char *)).

and also, this is the malloc()'s parameter in this code.

But I don't know how to mitigate this problem.

Help me please.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int val, i;
    char *mem;

    if (argc < 2)
        exit(1);

    val = atoi(argv[1]);

   if (val > 0) {
        mem = malloc(val * sizeof(char *));

      if (mem == NULL) {
          printf("Failure\n");
          exit(2);
      }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < val; i++) {
        mem[i] = 'A';
        printf("%c", mem[i]);
    }

    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `mmap()` might fix this.

Comment: Do you have a choice of the compiler? If yes, you're better off with C++ try...catch for exception handling.

Comment: Where exactly does the segmentation fault occur? What are your debugging results?

Comment: You are only storing characters (1 or 2 bytes) in your allocated memory, why are you are allocating enough space to store character pointers (probably 4 or more bytes)?

Comment: I am just curious about the integer overflow. so I tested some codes, but I couldn't fix this by myself.. well,, I used gdb debugger, when I input 1073741824 as an argument but, I found the argument was 0x7fffffffe408 as a input in gdb. I don't know why. This is larger number than my input number.

Comment: Why can't I think about exception handling? thank you, itsols. and I am going to do my research about mmap. thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Likely, in your C implementation, `int`, `size_t`, and `char *` are each 32 bits, four bytes. When `val` is 1073741824, `val * sizeof(char *)` overflows and, as it happens, produces zero. Then `mem = malloc(val * sizeof(char *));` allocates zero bytes of memory. It returns a valid pointer to zero bytes, not NULL, so your test for NULL does not cause your program to exit.

Then your program attempts to write 1073741824 bytes into the allocated memory. Since zero bytes were allocated, it overruns the space and crashes.

`mem = malloc(val * sizeof(char *));` should be `mem = malloc(val * sizeof(char));` or, better, `mem = malloc(val * sizeof *mem):`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This program printed "Failure" which means mem was null. Could you explain why "mem = malloc(val * sizeof * mem);" usage is more safe? I can't understand enough.

Comment: @JayCho: Suppose you use `mem = malloc(val * sizeof(char))` and, in the future, you want to change the code to use `int` instead of `char`. Then you have to change the definition of `mem` and the `malloc`. If you change one but not the other, the code will be broken. If you use `mem = malloc(val * sizeof *mem);`, then changing the definition of `mem` automatically changes the `malloc`. So the opportunity to create a bug is reduced.